# How to deploy a Polymer dart application

Tags: deployment, dart, polymer, dart2js

I have a dart application using Polymer.dart, i replace the dart.js file by the boot.js (in my index.html), an now i want to deploy this application in order to have a working javascript one.

But, when i launch the build.dart, i have :

```
Total time spent on web/index.html                           -- 504 ms
Total time                                                   -- 555 ms
```

but nothing is created, no more "out" folder. 
And when I do Pub Deploy, it create a "deploy" folder, but that version is not working (because the build.dart doesn't properly work i think).

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 8):

Right now, it's a two step process. I suspect this will get easier. In the meantime:

Create a build.dart that looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/builder.dart';
main() {
  build(entryPoints: ['web/index.html'], options: parseOptions(['--deploy']));
}
```

Take note, currently, a lot of warnings and hints are produced. You can ignore them for right now.

Comment: Thanks Seth, But i can not deploy the version which is now under /out, I have an error :

    Breaking on exception: Bad state: No elements

I signaled it in the bug tracker : https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12732

Comment: This isn't working for me: "Breaking on exception: FormatException: Could not find an option named "deploy".

Comment: @BrianSlesinsky I'm getting the same. :(

Comment: Since 0.7.1 the extra arguments are dropped and you need polymer/deploy.dart for `build(args, entry).then( (_) => deploy.main())`. However, I cant get the js from pub deploy to work with any browser :(

Comment: JS compilation does not works for me either.  On the one hand I'm really regretting about migrating to polymer from web_ui. On the other hand there were things in web_ui that did not work and now work in polymer.  Looks like web_ui was dropped half-way through the implementation, and polymer is only half-way completed.  Really sad :(

Comment: Since 0.7.6+ use: import 'package:polymer/builder.dart'; and then call build(entryPoints: ['web/index.html']);

Comment: Step 2 in the two step process is right clicking the entry point and choosing 'Build Polymer App', right? And step 3 is running the app as Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For the current version i have done these steps :

type on your console:
    dart build.dart --deploy
    dart2js out/web/index.html_bootstrap.dart -oout/web/index.html_bootstrap.dart.js

**index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...    
    <link rel="import" href="clickcounter.html">

    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ... 
    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <click-counter count="5"></click-counter>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**build.dart:**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/builder.dart';   
main(args) {
  build(entryPoints: ['web/aaa.html'],
    options: parseOptions(args));
}
```